# How do you search within a Polygon's coordinates on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I have implemented `react-google-maps` with the `<Drawing Manager />`.

**Not sure how to use the object it returns** from `onPolylineComplete` though. Doesn't seem to be documented either. I want to check some other locations appear in the area - so I can populate markers if they do.

So the Flow is:

1. A user should draw a line around an area (eg. Finsbury Circus, London.)
2. This calls `fetchNewsUpdateMarkers()`
3. That calls API, of objects, each one has **lat** and an **lng** value.
   3.5 I map through them, their **lat-lng** values are converted to google `LatLng` objects and...
4. I run `containsLocation()` and return the `true` ones to `markers` array.

So it all hedges on getting an array of polygon area coords from my `onPolylineComplete` returned obj

Code:

```
<DrawingManager
  defaultOptions={{
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
      ],
    },
  }}
  onPolylineComplete={(obj) => props.fetchNewsUpdateMarkers(obj)};
/>
```

and then...

```
fetchNewsUpdateMarkers: (obj) => {
  console.log(obj); // <-- this logs out as below
  let markers = [];
  let searchArea = new google.maps.Polygon({ paths: polygonCoords }); // <--that I hope to get from 'obj' somehow!

  let arrayOfAPIlocations = [
    { lat: 51.518420, lng: -0.088690 },
    { lat: 51.518110, lng: -0.087970 },
    { lat: 51.517601, lng: -0.180250 }
  ];

// ^^ only the *last* obj in this array is West London.
// The others are in the same district of East London.

// So maybe something like:

  arrayOfAPIlocations.map(each => {
    let convertedLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(each.lat, each.lng);
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(convertedLatLng, searchArea)) {
      markers.push(each);
    }
    return markers;
  });
}
```

This is what currently comes out of 'obj' :

[image]

Comment: [onPolygonComplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/drawing#DrawingManager.polygoncomplete) returns a [Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon) which has a `getPaths()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onOverlayComplete` event has the following signature:

```
onOverlayComplete?(e: google.maps.drawing.OverlayCompleteEvent): void
```

When the user has finished drawing a polygon, [`OverlayCompleteEvent.overlay` property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/drawing#OverlayCompleteEvent.overlay) returns the instance of `Polygon` object, the following snippet demonstrates how to determine whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon:

```
handleOverlayComplete(e) {

    const polygon = e.overlay;
    const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    const containsPlace = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(
        latLng,
        polygon
    );
    //...
}
```

Alternatively [`onPolygonComplete` event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/drawing#DrawingManager.polygoncomplete) could be utilized:

```
onPolygonComplete?(p: google.maps.Polygon): void
```

[This demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gvavr9) demonstrates how to highlight a marker if it contains within a drawn polygon